# Signature with certificate

Tags: certificate, signing

I'm trying to understand how it is working the signature of the file with a certificate.

I already understood how it's working for a 'basic' signature of file:

> - Bob wants to send to Alice "I'm signed"
> - Bob hashes "I'm signed", return "ABCDEF"
> - Bob encrypts the hash with his private key, return "101010"
> - Bob sends the encrypted part "101010" to Alice and the message "I'm signed"
> - Alice hashes the file, return "ABCDEF"
> - Alice decrypts the encrypted part "101010" with the public key of Bob, return "ABCDEF"
> - Alice makes match the two value that means that the message is really coming from Bob

I discussed today with someone working for a company that is dealing with authentification products, token, app for phone, cards etc..

The point is, the company is delivering two kinds of certificates with more or less strong value (depending on how much they succeed to identify the user above the process).

And as explained to me in a really blur way, "each user needs a certificate to allow him to sign his documents", "we encrypt with public key" (i think this point was probably not true), "the certificate contains the public key".

I tried to reach the point with looking to scheme: [wikipedia scheme](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Digital_Signature_diagram.svg/1280px-Digital_Signature_diagram.svg.png)

But I'm ever more lost.

I think Digital Signature is to manage with the first method that I described above and an Electronic signature is the fact to add the certificate to the process.

But how? Is someone could describe the steps, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we encrypt with public key

It is true, as it is called asymmetric encryption. Everybody (might) have the public key and therefore can encrypt messages send to the one holding the private key.

What probably confuses you is the mixed up thing: Signature and Encryption

- Bob wants to send to Alice "I'm signed"
- Bob hashes "I'm signed"
- Bob needs a certificate for the next steps

  - Bob generates a private key and a public key
  - Bob generates a certificate request containing the public key and signs it with the private key
  - Bob submits the request to CA
  - The CA **issues** a certificate (signs Bob's public key with the CA private key)
- Bob **signs** the hash with his **private key**
- Bob needs Alice's certificate for the next steps

  - Bob asks Alice for her public key (certificate)
  - Alice generates a private key and a public key
  - Alice generates a certificate request containing the public key and signs it with the private key
  - Alice submits the request to CA
  - The CA **issues** a certificate (signs Alice's public key with the CA 
    private key)
  - Alice sends Bob her public key (certificate)
- Bob **encrypts** the message, hash and signature with Alice's public key"
- Bob sends the encrypted data to Alice
- Alice **decrypts** the data with her **private key**
- Alice hashes "I'm signed" and **validates the signature** with Bobs **public key**

The key point is

- Alice is the only one who is able to read the message as she is the only one holding the private key to encrypt the data.
- Alice can be sure that the message is from Bob as he is the only one holding the key that produces the signature.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the therms. But then, where belongs the Certificate in the process?

Comment: The certificate is the `public key signed by a certificate authority (CA)`. If somebody requests a certificate the request is signed with the private key. The public key is then signed by the CA. Both together are often a*.pfx/*.p12 file. A cer/crt is usally a certificate (public key) and *.key is most often used for a private key file.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry but could you edit the process above including the request of certificate and so on? I understand the different "action" (like signing the public key etc...) but I still don't find clear the process/workflow. Thank you @daniel-fisher-lennybacon. I really apreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

@daniel-fisher-lennybacon:

Is it correct to do it like this too:

A *certificate request procedure* * made by **X** is:

- **X** **generates** a private key and a public key
- **X** **generates** a certificate a request containing the public key and **signs** it with the private key
- **X**
  **submits** the request to CA
- **X** CA **issues** a certificate (Bob's public key + **signs** Bob's
  public key with the CA private key)

--- Process ---

- Bob wants to send to Alice "I'm signed"
- Bob **hashes** "I'm signed"
- Bob **signs** the hash with his **private key**
- Bob needs Alice's certificate for the next step

  - Alice **proceed** a *certificate request procedure* * and **sends** the certificate (Alice's public key) to Bob
  - Bob **checks** that the certificate's signature is correct with the CA public key
- Bob **encrypts** the message, hash, and signature with Alice's public key"
- Bob **sends** all the encrypted content to Alice
- Alice **decrypts** the content and gets the message, hash, and signature
- Alice needs Bob's certificate (Bob's public key) to verify the signature

  - Bob **proceed** a *certificate request procedure* * and sends the certificate (Bob's public key) to Alice
  - Alice **checks** that the certificate's signature is correct with the CA public key
- Alice **check** that the signature coming from bob is correct with Bob's certificate (Bob's public key)

Is that correct?